# CSS/JS effects broken on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ive added CSS animations on text that are triggered by JS, they work fine in all browsers apart from Safari. When you click a line of text all lines of text fade out, on Safari, once you've clicked the text and go to the next page, if you click back the effect is triggered on page load and then resets and wont trigger on click.

Any idea how to fix this for Safari, you can see the effect on [this page](https://daisy.garywestjr.com/home)

This is the CSS animation:

```
.hometext.active {

  animation: fadeOutBottomLeft; /* referring directly to the animation's @keyframe declaration */
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.hometext.slide {

  animation: fadeOutTopRight; /* referring directly to the animation's @keyframe declaration */
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

This is the code im using to trigger the effects:

```
  jQuery(".hometext").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("slide");
    jQuery(".hometext").toggleClass("active");
        jQuery("#header-elementor").toggleClass("active");
  })
})
```

Comment: What are you doing to delay the page redirect?

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: The redirect to the next page is delayed until the animation completes; are you using a setTimer anywhere in your JS?

Comment: No Im not, would that  solve this issue? could you explain where to add the piece of code please?

Comment: Possibly, I'm trying to figure out how it is you're accomplishing that delayed redirect; the issue may have to do with how that is configured.

Comment: There is no delayed redirect, its just the time its taking to load the page

Answer (score 0):

Browser **backbutton** jQuery script.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
 alert("pop");
 // Write your code here when user click the browser back button.
});
```

After your comments if I understand correctly you want opposite animation on Browser **backbutton** when user clicked it. Simply it will not work for you. You have to understand how browser Back Button work.

```
window.history.replaceState(); //work exactly like pushstate bt this one replace the history instead of creating new one...
window.history.backward(); // To move backward through history, just fire this event...
window.history.forward();// To move forward through history ...
window.history.go(-1); // Go back to one page(or whatever value u passed) through history
window.history.go(1); // Go forward to one page through history..
```

I tested your site in **MacOS** `10.14` **Mojave** and **Safari** Version `13.1.1` It will work same like as chrome.

Comment: the css animation is working fine on all browsers that isnt the issue...its just how they are being triggered i believe. how would the code for the back button work? i dont need anything to be triggered when you click "back", i need the complete opposite, for nothing to be triggered on page load

Comment: Your `CSS` `fadeOut` animation own't save in browser history when you click the text. Browser History save page load data not after clicked event. You can't do opposite effect when you click the browser back button. One solution you have; you have to write `fadeIn` animation on page load. Page load will show `fadeIn` animation clicked text will show `fadeOut` animation from next page click the `backbutton` it will show `fadeIn` animation.

Comment: im not trying to have any effecton page load, i need nothing to be triggered, if you look at the page in chrome and click through to another page and then go back you will see how it is supposed to behave...then try in safari and you will see that it is behaving strangely

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
jQuery(".hometext").click(function(e) {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass("slide");
  jQuery(".hometext").toggleClass("active");
      jQuery("#header-elementor").toggleClass("active");
  setTimeout(()=> { 
    //remove the classes so they don't get reactived with back button
    //since you mentioned page load time is what's causing the delay, you may have to skip this
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("slide");
    jQuery(".hometext").toggleClass("active");
        jQuery("#header-elementor").toggleClass("active");
    //store the link in a custom attribute or any attribute and force redirect
   window.location.href = e.target.getAttribute('data-link');
    //set timeout to after animation
  },2000)
})
```

You would also have to strip your anchor tags of any href; unfortunately Safari is a very fickle browser when it comes to CSS.

Edit: Example html

```
<div data-link="/portfolio/elijah" class="elementor-element elementor-element-da798b1 hometext elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="da798b1" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
      < h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
        <a href="">DRUM&amp;BASSARENA</a>
      </h2>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just pasted this code in place of mine and the same thing is happening. Do I need to change anything?

Comment: set the href attributes of your anchor tags to "", and store the urls in a data attribute instead (assigned to your .hometext classed tags)

Comment: Cool i just tried this on the first line of text "DJ SNAKE", and its the same in safari, also storing the url as an attribute "data-link" didnt seem to work.

Comment: Try $(this).data("link") instead to extract it

Comment: I edited the code one last time; this time I passed the event as a param and used "e.target.getAttribute('data-link')". That should work, since i think "this" was refering to the entire document.

Comment: still no luck,pasting code from dev tools so u can see i added everything correctly
`<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-ccac5c2 hometext elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="ccac5c2" data-element_type="widget" data-fx="15" data-img="https://daisy.garywestjr.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/banner-optimised-1-scaled.jpg" data-link="https://daisy.garywestjr.com/portfolio/dj-snake/" data-widget_type="heading.default" style="">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
   <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="">DJ SNAKE</a></h2> </div>`

Comment: That looks correct; did you update the function to take in the event? It's definitely extractable. See this codepen: https://codepen.io/PavlosKaralis/pen/gOPxGJW

Comment: I did yes, the actual issue still remains, even if this data-link isnt working properly...im completely confused as to whats happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216758/discussion-between-gjjr-and-pavlos-karalis).